# How do I change the bottom navigation font to a custom on big cartel

Tags: css, custom-font, bigcartel

I've managed to change the font on the pages bar the bottom navigation bar, is this something that can be done? If so what is the code please??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.